# TALEND DI Job to create points-polygons and store them to postGis table

Tags: polygon, postgis, points, talend

which is the best way to create points and polygons starting from raw data and than store them into a postGIS table containing a geometry column?

Thanks

Comment: Could someone help me? I need to complete my job..

Comment: Create your own routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to elabore a more precise answer.

1. The first step is reading the `raw data`. There are many components to read data from : JSON, XML, Delimited text file, Excel, etc
2. I would read that data into a `tMap` component in order to get full control of the data being read.
3. Then, I would create a user routine that receives in input the raw data, and return the data in the format you want.
4. Then, I would use something like the `sPostGisInput` to insert this data into the PostGisDB

I don't know how postgis work, so perhaps you will need to adapt this solution a little bit in order to get it working.

Helpful link : [Strategy to load a set of files in Talend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295499/strategy-to-load-a-set-of-files-in-talend)

Helpful blog : http://bekwam.blogspot.com/

Helpful wiki : https://github.com/talend-spatial/talend-spatial/wiki