# how to load data (excel file) into sql-server using talend

Tags: talend

I am very new to using Talend, could some body tell me how to load a excel sheet to SQL-Server 2012?

I tried searching in Google but no help..

I can easily do it using ssis tasks, but much needed using Talend, I took an input as excel and tried making a DB connection but i dont know the connection string or I dont understand what to put as port, Database, schema, Additional parameters.

I tried following these links:

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295499/strategy-to-load-a-set-of-files-in-talend)

Comment: so, your question (and google searches) should be about **how to use SQL server as a data destination**. I can't believe  an experienced ETL developer as you doesn't know how the data flows.... http://bit.ly/1gorUfS

Comment: @SQL.injection.. :D i'm a fresher.. but thanks 4 d link :)

Comment: Talend has a youtube link..http://www.youtube.com/user/TalendChannel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What Talend Open Studio is ?

Talend Open Studio for Data Integration is an open source graphical development
environment for creating and deploying custom integrations between systems. It
comes with over 600 pre-built connectors that make it quick and easy to connect
databases, transform files, load data, move, copy and rename files, and connect
individual components in order to define complex integration processes.

and to answer to the question.

a raw file(excel,csv,xml,etc) put in a tfileInputdelimited then connected to tMSSQLoutput

[image]

the connection looks as shown in figure.

then to confiqure the sql server, goto to metadata,db connections-->right click -->create connection-->DB type-->sql server--> it works on sql server authentication so you need to create a user say user1 with some password-->then login-->password-->server_name-->port(1433 default in sql server)-->others left null(is ok)

file is successfully executed

This is something to be understood when trying Talend for the first time :D

Answer (score 2):

to solve your problem you need 3 components : 
    -Your Excel input
    -A tmap
    -A toutput
Join the excel input to the tmap and then the tmap to the dboutput.

Port, Database, Schema, Additional params refers to your database informations